# Нет установленного модуля в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Понадобился модуль `keyboard`. Этот модуль я установил через `pip`, в `pip freeze` он есть. Захожу в проект, который уже был создан в *IDE PyCharm*, и мне выдает ошибку:

> No module named 'keyboard'.

В это же время *Visual Studio Code* дает мне возможность использовать этот модуль.

Не знаете с чем это может быть связано? PyCharm перезапускал - не помогло.

И каким IDE Вы пользуетесь?

Comment: посмотрите используете ли вы ту же виртуальную среду куда установили пакет keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то, как ты написал, ты:

1. В командной строке Windows делаешь `py -m pip install keyboard` или типа того?
2. Заходишь в PyCharm и там не находишь этот Keyboard?

Если да, то:

PyCharm использует venv, это такая штука которая задает отдельную среду python, в которую можно устанавливать модули отдельно от общей установки.

Т.е. те модули, что у тебя в python через консоль винды и те модули что у тебя в проекте это два разных набора. Это позволяет тебе держать каждому проекту свои модули, и не заполнять общую установку модулями.

Тебе нужно открыть твой проект, и снизу PyCharm'а сделать вот так (вместо моей команды можешь использовать ту которую использовал в обычной консоли):

[image: Как сделать]

Использую PyCharm, это реально удобно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: В следующий раз попробуй более детально описывать последовательность своих действий, если будут подобные вопросы с "какая то функция не работает". =)